# How can I name a variable inside a class based on string value passed into its __init__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
class MyClass:
      __init__(self, some_string):
             self.some_string = anything
```

So similar to the DataFrame class of pandas where the columns can be referenced by appending the name of the column after the dot operator.

Like:

df.column_name_of_some_column

But the column name is a string value when read in from a CSV, for example. Hence the DataFrame classed has someway to create a variable from a string value.

How does it do that?

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Better use a dictionary.

Comment: change `self.some_string = anything` to `setattr(self, some_string, anything)`

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to use Dictionary and map the keys as per names.
You can add variables at runtime. But keep in mind that you don't override the
values.